# PayPal Preapproval key using Embedded Flow (lightbox)

Tags: paypal, lightbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

is it possible to request a preapproval key using Embedded Flow instead of redirecting the user to PayPal? I've done it with payKeys but I can't find examples of how to do it for future payments.

I tried changing the url of the light box to:

a) `/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?preapprovalkey=PA-XXXXX`

b) `/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/preapproval?preapprovalkey=PA-XXXXX`

none of them worked.

Comment: Pls refer to the answer in this post [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581647/paypal-preapproval-payment-using-embeded-light-box/35592582#35592582)

Comment: Hey jtello; I believe what you're asking is for the incontext flow of Express Checkout; seen her: https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/navigation?merchant=bigbox&page=classicCheckout ; does this look like what you're trying to accomplish using REST?

Comment: @GeekNinja thank you for your answer, after some research it seems that it's not possible to do what I was trying to do. When requesting a pre-approval key for adaptive payments you always have to redirect the user to full screen PayPal screen instead of using the embedded iframe flow. That is what I ended up doing.

Comment: hmph. I see. Ok. Well, glad you got it. Have a good one